# Python - Changing scenes' header color gives fever to CPUs

Tags: python

I have this script that changes the header color regarding the scene I am working in. The code is :

```
def header_color(self, context):
    global header_colors
    scene_name = bpy.context.screen.scene.name
    pref = bpy.context.user_preferences

    if scene_name == 'Editing table': pref.themes[0].info.space.header = header_colors[0]
    elif scene_name.startswith("Tag: "): pref.themes[0].info.space.header = header_colors[1]
    else: pref.themes[0].info.space.header = header_colors[2]

def register():
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.append(header_color)
def unregister():
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(header_color)
```

This function is incredibly CPU consuming. If I replace the conditional sequence for a straight...

```
pref.themes[0].info.space.header = header_colors[2]
```

...the cpu activity is back to normal.

Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why so CPU intensive?

Blender will call that function far more often than you think. Prove to yourself by adding a print statement in the function. that will explain the excessive CPU consumption.  It' s a neat idea but this is not the way to implement it. There are no [events](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=bpy.app.handlers#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post) that fire off upon scene change, else that would be a great idea for an event handler.

#### One possible approach

I'm hoping this will anger someone else into giving a better answer :)
An alternative is to code a dedicated menu for switching scenes.. something like this.. (use better class names than these )

- this gives a menu of scenes in the current blend
- lets you pick one
- switches color
- switches scene

--

```
import bpy

class SimpleSceneOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "scene.select_and_color"
    bl_label = "Simple Select Scene and Color"

    scene_name = bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        pref = context.user_preferences
        header_colors = [(1.0, 0.7, 0.7),(0.7, 1.0, 0.7),(0.7, 0.7, 1.0)]

        if self.scene_name == 'Editing table':
            col = 0
        elif self.scene_name.startswith("Tag: "):
            col = 1
        else:
            col = 2

        pref.themes[0].info.space.header = header_colors[col]
        context.window.screen.scene = bpy.data.scenes[self.scene_name]
        return {'FINISHED'}


class CustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        l = self.layout
        col = l.column()
        col.label(text="pick a scene")

        opname = "scene.select_and_color"

        for sc in bpy.data.scenes:
            col.operator(opname, text=sc.name).scene_name = sc.name


def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu(CustomMenu.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleSceneOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomMenu)
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.append(draw_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomMenu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleSceneOperator)
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(draw_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    # bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=CustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

could be triggered from 3dview, if you assign a shortcut to it, else the current code adds a menu item to the end of the info header, not ideal but gets the idea across.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer !!  I've just try this solution and although it is much more elegant, it still drives my cpus crazy. So, I think modal operators is the way to go. Do you know where I can find a list of events I can play with ? It's completely new to me :-)

Comment: Yep, didn't find anything either. I was thinking a timer of one second could limit the CPU access, what do you think ?

Comment: how about a popup menu :) I think that might work. with a callback operator

Comment: I may not understand. The user can change scenes using the pop up menu from the info bar. Would it be possible to intercept this ?

Comment: Ah alright !  I didn't see your last edit. Thanks !! Indeed, that would be an alternative but I try to limit my addon interface to the minimum. But my last question remains : intercepting the infobar menu ?? [and thanks again for your help !!]

Comment: not all events can be intercepted @Nikos_VSE i know of no way to intercept just that event..  I think you'll find that if you bind a keyboard shortcut to this custom scene selector menu, it will save you from having to use the mouse to navigate to the top bar and change it. A menu can be triggered from anywhere and all you need to do is press up/down enter.  That's all i can offer . maybe someone else knows.

Comment: It's already A LOT !!! Thank you so much for your help !!